# Создание proxy на домашнем компьютере

Tags: windows, openvpn, tcp-ip, proxy, ssh

Есть два компьютера, дома и на даче. У обоих ос Windows. Дома подключен с помощью Ethernet (ТТК), на даче ADSL (Ростелеком).> [@avp][1]> > Собираетесь ли с дачи соединяться с> работающим дома компом или хотите> эмулировать его на даче?Комп дома будет работать, нужно чтобы когда я заходил в интернет с компа на даче трафик шел через домашний комп. (ip адрес должен быть домашний), типо proxy.Возможно такое реализовать? Что для этого нужно? Посоветуйте какую почитать литературу по сетям и протоколам. Спасибо!  [1]: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/232/avp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот эта информация должна помочь в решении вопроса: [Настройка VPN сервера на Windows 7](http://winitpro.ru/index.php/2012/01/16/nastrojka-vpn-servera-na-windows-7/)

> В данной статье мы ознакомимся с тем, как можно организовать собственный VPN сервер на Windows 7 без использования стороннего софта

Comment: @gurzufnet спасибо, буду читать.

Answer (score 0):

Ставь 3proxy на домашний комп.Дом. комп. должен иметь настоящий ip адрес, а не серый за NAT'ом.Если ip серый, тогда teamview  используй. там можно создать vpn соединения.но это....

Answer (score 0):

Самый удачный вариант это [3proxy](https://helpsetup.ru/internet/domashnij_proksi_server_zaraza.html) Подробное руководство по ссылке. Ставится легко, доступен для всех операционных систем. Скачиваете не большой zip, распаковываете и далее все варианты настройки есть по ссылке.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/410885)

Comment: Спасибо за предупреждения. Я написал именно искренне и ссылку менять точно не буду. Это как то не по людски получается)))) Писать тут ответ получится очень много строк. Я описал так несколькими словами и дал ссылку где точно все описывается. Спасибо еще раз за предупреждения, не кто менять ничего не будет.